# Object reference sometimes set to an instance of an object (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie at C# and Unity who's been running into an error I just can't solve.

I have two classes, tileMap and rangeHandler. I have an array of tileTypes in tileMap with names, objects, and move costs, which I need to reference in rangeHandler to determine how far a character can walk. In tileMap, I have a function ( below) that returns the moveCost of a given tile, which is used without error in the pathfinding function.

```
public float tileCost(int sourceX, int SourceY, int targetX, int targetY)
     {

         tileData td = tileTypes[tiles[targetX, targetY]];

         float cost = td.moveCost;

         if (canEnter(targetX, targetY) == false)
         {
             return Mathf.Infinity;
         }
         //cosmetic increase to movement cost for diagonals
         if(sourceX != targetX && SourceY != targetY)
         {
             cost += 0.001F;
         }

         return cost;
     }
```

However, when I call this same function from rangeHandler, it tells me that tileTypes[tiles[targetX, targetY]] isnt set to an instance of an object, even when tiles[targetX, targetY] is the same values used in pathfinding. Below is where tileCost is called in tileMap, followed by where it's called in rangeHandler.

```
foreach (Node v in u.edges)
             {
                 //float alt = dist[u] + u.DistanceTo(v);
                 float alt = dist[u] + tileCost(u.x, u.y, v.x, v.y);
                 if (alt < dist[v])
                 {
                     dist[v] = alt;
                     prev[v] = u;
                 }
             }
```

and...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using UnityEngine;

 using Random = UnityEngine.Random;



 public class rangeHandler : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public tileMap map = new tileMap();
     public tileData td = new tileData();
     Dictionary<Node, Node> prev = new Dictionary<Node, Node>();
     Dictionary<Node, float> dist = new Dictionary<Node, float>();

     List<Node> unvisited = new List<Node>();



     public static bool[,] tilesHighlighted = null;





     public void getRange(int x, int y, int r)
      {
         r--;
          tilesHighlighted = new bool[tileMap.mapX, tileMap.mapY];
         foreach (Node v in tileMap.graph)
         {

                 dist[v] = Mathf.Infinity;
                 prev[v] = null;


             unvisited.Add(v);
         }



         //adds the source to the highlight array




         tilesHighlighted[x, y] = true;

          //then adds all adjacent tiles too


          foreach (Node n in tileMap.graph[x, y].edges)
          {



                 tilesHighlighted[n.x, n.y] = true;


                 dist[n] = map.tileCost(tileMap.graph[x, y].x, tileMap.graph[x, y].y, n.x, n.y);


                 extendRange(n.x, n.y, r, n);




          }
          map.generateRange(true);

      }
```

The error is on the first line of tileCost(), and I didn't get any answers on the Unity website. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the data in tileMap and tileData populated from?

Comment: tileData is a class with variables name, visual, and moveCost, which are manually set in the Unity inspector for each type of tile. Other than that I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have two instances of `tileMap`, one with a proper `tileTypes` array and one full of nulls or equal to null? (By the way, class names (and slighly less importantly methods and properties) should *really* start with a capital in C#. The convention makes it much easier for me and others to read and talk about code.) Also, what is the error?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm used to Java conventions. The error is that tileTypes[whatever] isnt set to an instance of an object

Comment: As for the two instances, I'm not sure, and I'm not sure how to go about checking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this line fails

```
 tileData td = tileTypes[tiles[targetX, targetY]];
```

either tileTypes is null or tiles[targetX,targetY] is null. so split into 2 lines

```
var idx = tiles[targetX,targetY];
var td = tileTypes[idx];
```

so you can see which one is null and use a debugger to inspect the values

Comment: I've tried that and found that when called from tileMap, there are no problems, but when called from rangeHandler, tileTypes is considered null. I'm sure there's just something small I'm missing...

Comment: I did what you suggested and as I thought tiles works fine, and tileTypes[idx] is null.